# Get AWS resources that don't have any tags using custom AWS Config policy not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-config

I'm working on a task to get all the resources in an account that don't have any tags on them. I came across AWS Config custom guard policies. To start with, I tried writing below Guard policy to filter just EC2 instances that don't have tags.

This is the policy:

```
let all_instances = Resources.*

rule instances_without_any_tags {
  %all_resources.Properties.Tags exists
}
```

I created this config rule using console. So I selected the "Resource type" as "AWS EC2 Instance" on the console while creating this rule.

However, I'm getting all the EC2 instances as either complaint(when used not exists operator) or non-complaint(for the above policy). But I have a mix of EC2 instances with and without tags.

Please help me in getting this custom policy correct.

Thanks!

Comment: the title and content talks about 2 different questions, title talks about finding resource without tags using config and content talks about fixing the policy, please clarify

Comment: This policy filters resources without tags. Isn't it? I'm new to Config. Based on this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/announcing-aws-config-custom-rules-using-guard-custom-policy/ I wrote this. And this is not filtering. So I think there is something wrong with the policy. If my question is not clear, please help me to put it in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the following instead:

```
tags not empty
```

This will check for the **tags property** not being empty in the resource **configuration item**.

The schema or "format" you're following is for CloudFormation. Instead, **you need to follow the schema used for AWS Config, which is the [configuration item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/config-item-table.html) schema.**
Each resources on AWS has a certain schema, the easiest way to find it is on the AWS Config console.

Finding resource configuration item format:

AWS Config console > **Rules** > filter on **resource type** > select your resource

[image: example configuration item]